# SELECT list is not in GROUP BY error but I got a result cleary

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

here is a code that I made.

```
SELECT
    substr(to_char(birthday, 'YYYY'), 1, 3)
    || '0',
    emp_type,
    AVG(pay)
FROM
emp2
WHERE
    substr(to_char(birthday, 'YYYY'), 1, 3) IN (
        '196',
        '197',
        '198',
        '199'
    )
GROUP BY
    substr(to_char(birthday, 'YYYY'), 1, 3),
    emp_type;
```

The code is simple, just group people by 1960s, 1970s ,1980s ,1990s and find an average pay by using `AVG(PAY)`

There is no problem or warnings when I run this code, but Oracle SQL Devloper shows me this.
[image: warning sign]

Sorry for my language. Anyway, the warning said the SELECT list is not same as GROUP BY.

I know this is a minor stuff ,but I think the one I SELECT is definitely in GROUP BY.
Please tell me whether I am right or wrong about my thought.
And here is the result and data table used in this code.

[image: result]
[image]

Comment: its a fault with sql developer, no need to worry about that.

Comment: Sqldeveloper is not able to identify your logic and warning you for something which best according to the logic developed in the sqldeveloper. Your query is 100% correct and you are good to go.

Comment: Hmm so not much problem in the future? I just worried whether it affects in the future stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your group by needs to contain the columns you selected. In your case, you selected 2 columns:

```
SELECT 
    substr(to_char(birthday, 'YYYY'), 1, 3) || '0',
    emp_type,
    ...
```

but you missed the concatenated '0' in your group by clause, so the 2 columns in your `group by` are not the same as the ones in your `select` clause.

```
GROUP BY
    substr(to_char(birthday, 'YYYY'), 1, 3),
    emp_type;
```

Try changing that to

```
GROUP BY
    substr(to_char(birthday, 'YYYY'), 1, 3) || '0',
    emp_type;
```